# SQL Server Stored Procedure Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-dynamics

I've recently inherited an internal ASP.NET website that uses SQL Server 2008 as the backend server. SQL Server has a database, `Database1`, with several `Companies` within each database, all with the same set of tables.

For example:

```
Database1
     Company1.Table1
     Company1.Table2
     Company2.Table1
     Company2.Table2
```

The website calls several stored procedures. However, the stored procedures have been coded to select data from a hard coded Company Name.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Company1.Table2
```

This has worked fine to date because the web site has only been linked to `Company1`. The plan is now to also link the website to `Company2`. In effect, `Company 2` is being used as a test bed, via a separate setup on IIS

Is there an easy way, maybe pass through the company name to the stored procedure, to be able to retain this setup?

It's also been suggested that an alternative would be a separate instance of SQL, so I could use the same `database\company` name which would mean very little changes.

Another suggestion was to simply to copy the stored procedures from `Company 1` to `Company 2` and change the hard coded name in `Company 2`?

Sorry if I'm a little vague but this has been dropped on my desk this morning, and I'm neither a SQL Server or website expert.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Cheers

Justin

Comment: A separate database, or instance, would be a better choice for testing.  It isolates the test environment from production.  Passing a table name into a stored procedure means either using dynamic SQL or coding the procedure to dispatch based on the argument and execute the correct statement(s).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way, maybe pass through the company name to the
>   stored procedure, to be able to retain this setup?

The easiest way to retain this setup (without knowing anything about the ASP.net code) is to run a seperate copy of the whole database for testing. I would suggest a third copy for development but that is verging off topic.

All your above methods are feasible but simply copying the database means that you don't have to change any code inside the database. The database name will hopefully not be hardcoded in the ASP.net code, so you should be able to point it to the new database easily.

This gives you the added benefit of having independant datasets for testing, so you're not chasing a moving target while testing changes.

Brief comments on the other suggested methods:

> maybe pass through the company name to the stored procedure

Not only would this mean refactoring the stored procedures, it would probably require some dynamic SQL and possibly open you up to SQL injection (not necessarily a problem since it's internal).

> Another suggestion was to simply to copy the stored procedures from Company 1 to Company 2 and change the hard coded name in Company 2?

Again, this would involve refactoring the stored procedures (although just with a find/replace) and I would suggest it would need full testing to prove the refactoring has worked properly.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've gone down the path of a seperate database. Cheers for the advice

Answer (score 0):

This will merge the data from two different database tables with same table structure

```
SELECT * FROM Company1.Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Company2.Table2
```